# In which situation to declare instance variable?

Tags: java, oop, processing, instance-variables

I have simple class :

```
class Blah { 

  private PApplet applet; 
  private float value;

  public Blah(PApplet theApplet, theValue) {
    applet = theApplet;
    value = theValue;
  }

  public float getX() {
    return PApplet.map(value, applet.min, applet.max, applet.c1, applet.c2);
  }

}
```

I wonder now, is it ok to have `getX()` as described?

Shouldn't I declare a variable `xpos` and a setter and getter for it?
How do I decide whether I should declare an instance variable or not in such situations? (where one instance variable value is dependent on another instance variable)

With an `xpos` instance variable I would have:

```
class BlahBla {
  private PApplet applet;
  private float value;
  private float xpos;

  BlahBla(PApplet theApplet, float theValue) {
    applet = theApplet;
    value = theValue;
    xpos = PApplet.map(theValue, applet.min, applet.max, applet.c1, applet.c2);
  }

  public getX() {
    return xpos; 
  }

  public setX(float theValue) {
    xpos = map(theValue, applet.min, applet.max, applet.c1, applet.c2);
  }

}
```

Advantages to have `xpos` as instance variable:

- I do not do mapping each time `getX()` is called

Disadvantages to have `xpos` as instance variable:

- more code
- confusion when using setter method

Considerations:

- Shouldn't a setter assign the value directly to `xpos`? Should any manipulation (like mapping) be allowed here?
- `xpos` should be linked to `value` - is it valid to create `setX()` without parameters? In case I have `xpos` variable and `set(float theValue)` as public - this breaks the link between `xpos` and `value` as using setter allow to assign any data other than `value`.

Comment: Your original implementation doesn't call for a setter, just because you add a getter doesn't mean you need a setter. If something should never change do not provide a setter

Comment: Assuming xpos doesn't change it makes sense from an efficiency point of view to keep it as a field but from a good stsndards point of view it makes little difference if you create xpos on demand, lazy load it or create when the object is constructed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have only a getter as per your first version: Don't have a field:

- simpler code
- don't have to worry about the case where `value` etc changes in the life of the object (might not happen today, but might happen one day)
- less code
- it's premature optimization:

The only reason to store the calculated attribute in a field is "performance", but if you're thinking about it at design time that itself is a big mistake. Only consider using a field if you have hard evidence there actually is a performance problem. Also, if you only call the getter for some objects, it would be a waste to calculate it for all objects.

It is not necessary, or meaningful, to have a setter in either case.

Comment: In regards to your comment I need to specify one thing - getX() in first version is called when object is displayed (60 fps) and moreover in other methods like checking if object is within the borders of a screen (if it moves) etc. So I think it will not be good to perfom mapping in getX() method... So far performance is ok but is it a good practice ? I thought that whenever I have x field, its getter should always point to x, without any mutations...

Comment: Well ar 60 fps it seems like it could be a candidate for caching, and if you decide to do that make a private setX() method that creates and sets the calculated field and call it from your setters of other fields whose value affects the calculated value. Even so, if it performs OK as is, I would leave it and do other work. It's OK for getters to return calculated values. It's not OK for getters to modify state. Saving the value returned is caching and not considered "modifying state".

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of having a field and a getter is that it will act as a caching system, so that you won't be computing the same value again and again (which can be good as it can be horrible depending on what you are doing). The con is that it will lead to a less clear code and it can consume more memory if your value is big.

To me, you should use a field and a getter (not a setter if the value has not to be changed, remember the open/closed principle), but again it depends on how you are planning to use your class.

Also, yes you can perform operations such as mapping in the setter, that's actually why you should use setters: you disallow direct access to your field so you have a control point over your field modification, which can be used to perform operations on the parameters (like checking them for null values, for example)